# How to sum values of an identical key

Tags: python, sum, key-value

I need Python to read a .txt file and sum up the hours each student has attended school for the year. I need help understanding how to do this when the same student has multiple lines in the file. The .txt file looks something like this:

John0550
John0550
Sally1007

And the ultimate result I'm looking for in Python is to print out a list like:

John has attended 1100 hours
Sally has attended 1007 hours

I know I can't rely on a dict() because it won't accommodate identical keys. So what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you already have a way to split name and hours attented on each line ?

Comment: Yes sir. In reality, the name is actually a student number positioned at line[22:31] and the attended hours is at line[134:140].

Comment: You can still use a dict. Just include some logic to update the value in the dict if the key already exists as you iterate through the lines.

Comment: Ok I will try to provide you an anwser below, but in my opinion dicts are the best way to achieve this, I will show how in my opinion.

Comment: Ok roger that. I assumed dict was a total no-go. That's what I get for assuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you already have a function named `split_line` that returns the student's name / hours attented pair for each. Your algorithm would look like :

```py
hours_attented_per_student = {}  # Create an empty dict

with open("my_file.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        name, hour = split_line(line)

        # Check whether you have already counted some hours for this student
        if name not in hours_attented_per_student.keys():
             # Student was not encountered yet, set its hours to 0
             hours_attented_per_student[name] = 0

        # Now that student name is in dict, increase the amount of hours attented for the student
        hours_attented_per_student[name] += hours
```

Comment: This appears to be working! Much appreciated Alex!

Comment: Hate to uncheck the answer, but after further inspection this is only working for the students that have multiple lines in the file. If a student does not have two lines in the file, it's setting the hours to zero. My fault if I didn't clarify well enough that not every student has multiple lines.

Comment: Actually no. Every time a line is encountered, the amount of hours associated to the student is added to its dictionnary value. So even with a user with a single line in file, it should work. Make sure you indented correctly your code. Bad indentation may indeed cause the error you are having.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the code and reentered it and now the single line students have the correct hours. Not sure what was wrong the first time, but working now!  Answer re-checked. Thanks again Alex!

Comment: Cool you got it !

Answer (score 1):

A [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could be helpful here:

```py
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO

# Simulate File
with StringIO('''John0550
John0550
Sally1007''') as f:
    # Create defaultdict initialized at 0
    d = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    # For each line in the file
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Split Name from Value
        name, value = re.split(r'(^[^\d]+)', line)[1:]
        # Sum Value into dict
        d[name] += int(value)

# For Display
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'John': 1100, 'Sally': 1007}
```

---

Assuming values are already split and parsed:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

entries = [('John', 550), ('John', 550), ('Sally', 1007)]

d = defaultdict(int)
for name, value in entries:
    # Sum Value into dict
    d[name] += int(value)

# For Display
print(dict(d))
```

Comment: `defaultdict(lambda: 0)` could be just `defaultdict(int)`.

Comment: This works too. Man what an awesome community this is. Thank you Henry!